# when a user sign in he can fill the form only once

Tags: php, mysql, post, pdo

I created a customer area which after registration he must fill out a form which must be confirmed by the administrator to give him a meeting appointment
but the problem is that a user can fill the form several times how to do for each user can fill the form only once

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="insertion1.php" >
       <table>
             <tr> <td><input type="checkbox" name="prsnphysique" value="Je suis une personne physique." required="true">Je suis une personne physique </td>
             <td> <label>Type de compte bancaire</label>
                     <select name="typeban">
                            <option>Compte depot</option>
                            <option>Compte CEDAC</option>
                            <option>Compte personnel BEA</option>
                     </select></td></tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Nom</label>
            <input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nom" required="true">
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>Prenom</label>
            <input type="text" name="prenom" placeholder="Prenom" required="true">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Date de naissance</label>
            <input type="date" name="nais" placeholder="Date de naissance" required="true">
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>Lieu de naissance</label>
            <input type="text" name="lnais" placeholder="Lieu de naissance" required="true">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Prenom du pere</label>
            <input type="text" name="pprenom" required="true" placeholder="Prenom du père">
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>Nom de la mere</label>
            <input type="text" name="mnom" required="true" placeholder="Nom de la mère">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Prenom de la mere</label>
            <input type="text" name="mprenom" required="true" placeholder="Prenom de la mère">
        </td>
        <td>    
                     <label>Numero de l'acte de naissance</label>
                   <input type="number" name="actenais" required="true" placeholder="Numero de l'acte de naissance">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Piece d'identite presente</label>
            <select name="typepie">
                <option>Carte d'identite</option>
                <option>Permis de conduire</option>
                <option>Passeport</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>Numero de la piece d'identite</label>
            <input type="number" name="numpi" required="true" placeholder="Numero de la piece d'identite">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Delivree le</label>
            <input type="date" name="datedeliv" required="true" placeholder="Delivree le">
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>delivree par</label>
            <input type="text" name="delivpar" required="true" placeholder="Delivree par">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>Profession</label>
            <input type="text" name="prof" required="true" placeholder="Profession">
        </td>
        <td>
                     <label>Numero de telephone</label>
            <input type="number" name="numero" required="true" placeholder="Numero de telephone">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
                     <label>E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required="true" placeholder="E-mail">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
              <td>
                     <label>Pieces justificatifs</label><br><br>
                     Acte de naissance  <input type="file" name="actenaisss" required="true"><br><br>
                     Piece d'identite  <input type="file" name="piec" required="true"><br><br>
                     Certificat de residence/ Facture d'electricite<br>Hebergement/ Contrat location  <input type="file" name="resid" required="true">
              </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
       <input type="submit" name="suiv" value="Suivant">
    </form>
```

So I want that when a user sign in he can fill the form only once how can I do this
Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Well you should validate that on the server, and return an error if its the case

Comment: How I can do that I need some help with that

Comment: It's just simple logic - keep a record of which users have submitted the form before! It would be the same if this was a paper form, yes?

Comment: For example, you could make a database table (or just a field in the users table maybe) which stores a "true" value when the user has submitted the form the first time. Then, each time the form is submitted, check that value for the logged-in user (using a SELECT query), and if they submitted it before, just display a message instead of saving the data again. You can also use the same technique to stop the form even being displayed, because you can check the database at the time the user tries to load the page containing this form.

Comment: where am i suppose to wite the code in the form or il the insert code i did them separately if you give me a little example that would be so much helpful

Comment: I told you where to write it - there are two places you need it